# What provides /usr/local//lib/python3.7/site-packages/py_arch_spec.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Tags: python

Ubuntu 20 install on amd64 with pythin 3.7 and pytorch

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So you're using Ubuntu Core 20 and not Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  The default python3 is newer than 3.7

Comment: Try `dpkg -S  /usr/local//lib/python3.7/site-packages/py_arch_spec.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. That will tell you which Ubuntu package provides it.

Comment: Nothing provides it - no official package installs files in `/usr/local`.